# Finding all XML nodes between each two processing instructions

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using `XPath` or XSLT 1.0, I need to find each node between processing instructions `<?start?>` and `<?end?>`. The following code:

```
//node()[preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()[self::processing-instruction('start')] 
following-sibling::processing-instruction()[ self::processing-instruction('end')]]`,
```

works, but naturally, it only selects nodes between the first PI and the last PI. Is there any way how to select only the nodes that are between each start - end pair?

```
<root>
    abc

<?start?>def<Highlighted
    bold="yes"><Highlighted italic="yes">ghi</Highlighted></Highlighted>jkl
    <?pi?>
    <table>
      <Caption>stu</Caption>
    </table>vw

<?end?>
xy<?start?> 
abc <Caption>def</Caption> ghi<?end?> jkl
</root>
```

Comment: The question is marked as XSLT and as XPath. Do you need a pure XPath solution or do you want to solve that with XSLT? Also, can you use XSLT/XPath 2.0 (like `<xsl:template match="root"><xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="processing-instruction('start')">...`?

Comment: If it is not possible to use a pure XPath solution, XSLT 1.0, but not XSLT 2.0 can be used as well. Sorry about forgetting to mention it.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added an XSLT 1.0 approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 example that uses `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` to find and output the nodes between those pairs of processing instructions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="processing-instruction('start')">
        <xsl:if test="self::processing-instruction('start')">
            <group>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="processing-instruction('end')">
                    <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[position() ne last()]"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </group>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result for your sample is

```
<group>def<Highlighted bold="yes">
      <Highlighted italic="yes">ghi</Highlighted>
   </Highlighted>jkl
    <?pi?>
    <table>
        <Caption>stu</Caption>
    </table>vw

    </group>
<group> 
    abc <Caption>def</Caption> ghi</group>
```

Using XSLT 1.0 you can compute the intersection of nodes following the `start` pi and preceding the `end` pi:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="start" match="root/node()[not(self::processing-instruction('start'))]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('start')[1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="end" match="root/node()[not(self::processing-instruction('end'))]" use="generate-id(following-sibling::processing-instruction('end')[1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="processing-instruction('start')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('start')">
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="following-sibling::processing-instruction('end')[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="following-start" select="key('start', generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="preceding-end" select="key('end', generate-id($end))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="intersect" select="$following-start[count(. | $preceding-end) = count($preceding-end)]"/>
        <group>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$intersect"/>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. However, I now need to have nodes OUTSIDE the "start - end" intersections at the output as well. This means that at the output: a) nodes at the intersection of start - end PI will be in the group element b) any node outside the intersection will be printed unchanged. Please note that the input document may have no start - end processing instruction pair.

Comment: @L.Vareka, consider to ask a new question with the clear description of the wanted output as a code sample.

Comment: OK. The new question is available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054922/grouping-xml-nodes-between-each-two-processing-instructions-using-xslt-1-0