# Grouping XML nodes between each two processing instructions using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using XSLT 1.0, I need to group each node between processing instructions `<?start?>` and `<?end?>`. The nodes outside of this pair should be unchanged at the output.

First, I need to find a way how to select only the nodes that are between each start - end pair. Suppose we have an example input XML:

```
<root>
  abc
  <?start?>
    def<Highlighted bold="yes">
    <Highlighted italic="yes">ghi</Highlighted>
    </Highlighted>jkl
    <?pi?>
    <table>
      <Caption>stu</Caption>
    </table>vw
  <?end?>
  xy
  <?start?> 
  abc <Caption>def</Caption> ghi
  <?end?>
  jkl
</root>
```

Furthermore, I need to have nodes OUTSIDE the "start - end" intersections at the output as well. This means that at the output: a) nodes at the intersection of start - end PI will be in the group element b) any node outside the intersection will be printed unchanged. Note that the input document may also have no start - end processing instruction pair.

For example, from the given input, the output should be as follows:

```
<root>
  abc
  <group>
    def<Highlighted bold="yes">
    <Highlighted italic="yes">ghi</Highlighted>
    </Highlighted>jkl
    <?pi?>
    <table>
      <Caption>stu</Caption>
    </table>vw
   </group>
   xy
   <group> 
     abc <Caption>def</Caption> ghi
   </group>
   jkl
 <root>
```

A part of this question has already been answered in [Finding all XML nodes between each two processing instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769645/finding-all-xml-nodes-between-each-two-processing-instructions). But I struggle with printing out nodes outside of the group element without duplicating any node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('start')">
        <group>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
        </group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::processing-instruction('end')[1]/following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('end')"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT uses a recursive approach of processing first child node and the first following-sibling node().

The first template processes all nodes except start and end pis.
The second template adds the `group` element to the elements between start pi and end pi. Third template helps remove the end pi.

Answer (score 0):

Change the template for `root` to

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', '') | processing-instruction('start') | node()[preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()[1][self::processing-instruction('end')]] | key('end', '')"/>          
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

so the whole code becomes

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="start" match="root/node()[not(self::processing-instruction('start'))]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('start')[1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="end" match="root/node()[not(self::processing-instruction('end'))]" use="generate-id(following-sibling::processing-instruction('end')[1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('start', '') | processing-instruction('start') | node()[preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()[1][self::processing-instruction('end')]] | key('end', '')"/>          
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('start')">
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="following-sibling::processing-instruction('end')[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="following-start" select="key('start', generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="preceding-end" select="key('end', generate-id($end))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="intersect" select="$following-start[count(. | $preceding-end) = count($preceding-end)]"/>
        <group>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$intersect"/>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not very well tested but I hope it covers all nodes before, in between and after the pis.

Comment: This works correctly unless the structure of the input document is more complicated, e.g. there is a subroot element inside the root element in the example input.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I like the recursive solution from @Lingamurthy CS
Her a slightly  different key based solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="pi" match="root/node()"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()
                  [self::processing-instruction('start') or self::processing-instruction('end') ][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="processing-instruction('start') | 
                                     processing-instruction('end') |
                                     key('pi', '')"/>          
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('start')">
        <group>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="key('pi', generate-id())
                 [not(self::processing-instruction('end'))]" />
        </group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('end')">
       <xsl:apply-templates 
           select="key('pi', generate-id())[not(self::processing-instruction('start'))]" />
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```